# Webform: request submitted values in all page breaks

Tags: webforms

I have multiple page breaks in a webform. 
Can I get all the values submitted in all previous page break? Actually I can get only the values for one previous page break(the last one submitted).

For example if i'm in the page break 4 only can request the values submitted in page break 3 not in all the previous (2 and 1). The other values are not present.

I'm using the hook_form_alter.

Getting the info from $form_state["input"]["submitted"]

```
    function custom_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {    
      if(substr($form_id,0,20 ) == 'webform_client_form_') {   
        dsm($form_state["input"]["submitted"]);
        //Only info from one page break(previous)
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve submitted values across all pages from `$form_state['storage']['submitted']`.

Note that this represents values from *past* pages and not the current page. Here is the code I use to get them all (past & current) page values into a single array:

```
$values = _webform_client_form_submit_flatten($node, $form_state['values']['submitted']);
$values += $form_state['storage']['submitted'];
```

Comment: Thanks! Works fine.

(My php version don't admit "+=", I used function "array_replace")

Comment: @rubofvil Glad to help. Please click the checkbox and the up arrow next to this answer.

Comment: I don't have enough points yet to vote, sorry.(I will do)